# Can't implement pure virtual function from SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

SFML defines this virtual function:

```
class SFML_GRAPHICS_API Drawable
{
public: virtual ~Drawable() {}

protected:
    friend class RenderTarget;
    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const = 0;
};
```

And in my code on `surface.hpp` I created the following class:

```
class surface : public sf::Drawable
{
    friend class vertex;
public:
    surface(sf::Vector2f p1, sf::Vector2f p2, sf::Vector2f p3, sf::Vector2f p4);
    ~surface();
    vertex& operator[](int i);
private:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states);
};
```

And in `surface.cpp` I provide the implementation for `draw`:

```
void surface::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states){
    // ...
}
```

But when I run my code and try to `surface mySurface(/* ... */);` from my `main.cpp`, I get the error:

```
SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp:69:18: Unimplemented pure virtual method 'draw' in 'surface'
```

I'm almost 100% sure I implemented it right, so why isn't clang letting me compile? I also tried to define `draw` inside the definition of `surface` in `surface.hpp` but nothing helps...

Comment: Try: `void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override;` The missing `const` means you've declared a new method instead of overriding the existing virtual method. And, the `override` keyword is just good practice and should make the error message more clear when the function prototype doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm almost 100% sure I implemented it right

Good thing you said "almost".

```
virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const = 0;
                                                             ^^^^^
```

The `const` is part of the function signature! It must appear in your implementation too:

```
class surface : public sf::Drawable 
{
    // ...
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
                                                                 ^^^^^
};
```